# Use different contructors of disposable class

Tags: c#, validation, null, ldap

I have a very simple helper class to validate credentials. Sometimes the domain has a value, sometimes not. Depending on this, a different constructor for `PrincipalContext` must be used. `PrincipalContext` is disposable, so I am using `using`. It looks ugly, and recommendations?

```
public class LDAPManager : ILDAPManager
{
    public bool ValidCredentials(string username, string password, string domain)
    {
        using (var context = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(domain) ? new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain) : new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
        {
            return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As the constructor of PrincipalContext which only takes a `ContextType` as parameter internally calls this constructor

```
public PrincipalContext(ContextType contextType, string name, string container,  
      ContextOptions options, string userName, string password){}
```

by passing `null` for the name I would change your method to

```
public class LDAPManager : ILDAPManager
{
    public bool ValidCredentials(string username, string password, string domain)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(domain)) {
            domain = null;
        }
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
        {
            return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
        }
    }
}
```

based on the valid comment of [Lightness Races in Orbit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/2503/lightness-races-in-orbit) it can be that this implementation will change sometime. So be careful.

After getting this comment, I also noticed some naming issue with this method. Based on the [naming guidlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4df752aw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), you should use verbs or verb phrases to name your methods.
So the method would be better named `ValidateCredentials()`.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't think to check how the constructor works internally.

Comment: Just be careful - this somewhat relies on implementation details. Is it guaranteed by the interface of `PrincipalContext`? Is it stated in the documentation? If not, I wouldn't go down this route.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are right, as these sources aren't avaible. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298328) does explain what `null` name means.

Comment: @svick: Yep this looks fine then. Actually it would appear to contradict the question as the `name` parameter is not optional and there is only one constructor? But perhaps that's just me not understanding C# (as I am not a C# developer). Carry on :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's just the documentation for that one constructor overload, if you look at [the list of constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.principalcontext), you'll notice that there is an overload without `name`.

Comment: @svick: Oh, right, yes. Sorry, I find MSDN confusing to navigate. The documentation does not make it clear that `PrincipleContext(ContextType.Domain)` is strictly and reliably equivalent to `PrincipleContext(ContextType.Domain, null)` (the search for this guarantee is what I was trying to get at) but I suppose it's probably dependable enough.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to run with one method, I'd use some spacing.

However, since you're essentially using "domain" as an optional parameter. Consider two methods instead. This will require a change to your interface, probably.

Also, there's no reason this could not be a static method, except for the fact you have it in an interface.

Finally, a class with one method is not really doing much. Is there somewhere else this could be better placed? Perhaps as an extension method?

With all that in mind:

**If you're hell-bent on sticking with one method:**

```
public class LDAPManager : ILDAPManager
{
    public bool ValidCredentials(string username, string password, string domain)
    {
        using (var context = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(domain) ? 
            new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain) : 
            new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
        {
            return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
        }
    }
}
```

**If you want a more sensible multiple method system**

```
public class LDAPManager : ILDAPManager
{
    public bool ValidCredentials(string username, string password, string domain)
    {
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
        {
            return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
        }
    }

    public bool ValidCredentials(string username, string password)
    {
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
        }
    }
}
```